# Vb.NET indexed property

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am more familiar with c# than i am with vb.net but i am trying to figure out how to write the vb.net equivalent of:

```
public float this[int row, int col]
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Is this possible in vbnet?

If i knew what this type of property was called i may have had better luck on google

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using http://converter.telerik.com, I get this:

```
Public Default Property Item(row As Integer, col As Integer) As Single
    Get
        ' ...
    End Get

    Set
        ' ...
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know Item was a class indexer

Comment: The Default keyword allows you to do the myobject(0,0) instead of needing to do myobject.Item(0,0).

Comment: As a tip, be careful not to overuse it in performance sensitive areas such as large matrix operations as it can cause a performance hit from my experience.